# Pagination limit does not working in getStream iOS

Tags: ios, getstream-io

Pagination limit not working in GetStream iOS.
I m trying to fetch all the comments of an activity , I have set the limit as a large number but still getStream is returning only 15-20 comment. 
Even if pass pagination as .none , getStream return limited comments only. 
How can I fetch all the comment for a activity in a single call , I don't need any pagination.

```
 Client.shared.reactions(forActivityId: state.activity.id, 
                         kindOf: ReactionKind.comment, 
                         extraDataTypeOf: ReactionExtraData.self,
                         userTypeOf: SpokStreamUser.self,
                         pagination: Pagination.limit(100),
                         withActivityData: false) {[weak self] (result) in }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we have [max limit 25](https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#reaction_pagination) and you have to use pagination.